# How to implement the orange color when you follow a permalink?

Tags: javascript

Like what you see when following this link:

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496731/how-do-i-remove-unnecessary-resources-from-my-project/1496798#1496798)

It's cool!

Comment: it not just css, its some javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is done with jQuery. It's basically just animating the background color of the div itself. Assuming the background color of the div is set to orange to begin with:

```
$(".specialDiv").animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 1000);
```

As for setting the bg to orange to begin with, this is likely done as a result of the hash value in the URL. You can get that value with `window.location.hash`

#### Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations

Comment: Note that you'll need an additional plugin to animate colors.

Comment: Color animations are covered here: http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations

Comment: Great,but it's a pity location.hash can't be used by server side,otherwise I'll import this plugin only when there is #...