# Is there any tool to cleanup the unused or ambigous Images and CSS from the ASP.NET Web Application Project?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution)

Is there any tool to cleanup the unused or ambiguous Images and CSS from the ASP.NET Web Application Project without too much of effort, if there is a plugin for the same like Resharper that would be ideal.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will help you find unused CSS: http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/

Answer (score 1):

There's also http://unused-css.com