# Removing unused image from Visual Studio Project

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution)

I'm looking for a tool that can remove the unused images from Visual Studio.. but I couldn't find any tool so I'm thinking to write small program.. Since there are a lot of files in entire solution, I'm worrying about performance..

I heard that SharpDevelop is using Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm for text searching. What about file searching? Do I still have to go thru each and every files one by one and read all texts from each file and search the text?

Any idea would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I think I didn't make myself clear enough. Sorry about that. I like to get the following advice from you guys.

1. Do you know any tool that can remove(delete) the unused images from WPF/Silverlight project/sln?
2. What are the best practices for writing a program that can do "text searching" in a lot of files?

Thanks.

Comment: "Any idea would be appreciated." I couldn't have put it better myself - what is it you want to do?  Are you talking about resources?  You can just delete them from the filesystem.

Comment: Neil, Thanks. I updated the questions. I have the list of images and I'm planning to write a program that can tell me whether we are using those images in any XAML or cs files... Thanks. Feel free to let me know if you are still not clear. Thanks.