# VS2010 delete unused images/files

Tags: asp.net, image, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution)

In a webapplication we have a lot of images and some of them are not used/referenced anymore. Is there way (tool or something) to get a list of all these unused files or/and delete them?

Comment: I be it could be tricky to decide whether image is referenced somewhere or not. Let's imagine some js like: `$('img#foobar').attr('src', '/path' + '/to' + '/image.' + ext);`

Comment: There is a free extension called Code Maid -- https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496 -- that will find unused images or files and will search everywhere including css and js files.

Comment: There's an open-source VS extension that does that https://github.com/jitbit/vs-unused-image-finder (disclaimer: I'm a conributor!)

Answer (score 3):

A manual approach - If you have Resharper installed, you can right-click and choose "Find Usages" this will look in your project for a reference to the selected image.

Comment: I want to upvote you, but I just can't. That would be so painful for more then a few items.

Comment: FYI - You can select more than a single image file at a time.

Comment: The Resharper "Find Usages" doesn't find references in css files.

Comment: nor in jquery like mentioned in comment on OP