# Check if all resources in .resx are used and find calls to nonexisting ones

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resx

I have a large Resources.resx file in my application and I'm accessing them with

```
MyResources.GetString("res1");
```

How to check that for every entry "Entry" in the .resx file exists at least one call `MyResources.GetString("Entry")` (which means every resource is used somewhere)

, and how to check that for every call `MyResources.GetString("Entry")` exists a resource with the name "Entry" (there are no call to nonexisting resources) ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you need to get rid of unused resources - that can be a hard one. I do not know of an easy way (except code searching) that will say if you are using a certain resource. For the second requirement, I'd recommend using a wrapper of the resource retrieval that would handle the absence of the resource in a safe manner.

Comment: If you use wrapper solution, you may add Debug.Assert calls that check that resource exists. Each time unused resource is referenced in Debug mode the Assertion Failed window will pop up.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? A tool to check unused resx entry
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26598684

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but fiddly, to discover unused resources:

(1) Ensure Code Analysis warning CA1811 is turned on.

(2) In your Resources.Designer.CS file (or other applicable designer file) comment out the following lines:

```
[global:: System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute( ...
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global:: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
```

(3) Change the class to a static class by putting the word "static" in front of "class":

```
 internal static class Resources {
```

(4) Comment out the default constructor.

(5) Comment out any “InternalsVisibleTo” lines (these are usually in “AssemblyInfo.cs”).

(6) Compile your program. Now you should be warned about any unused resources.

(7) Remove your unused resources. (Note that changing any resources will regenerate the Resources.Designer.cs file.)

I'm not sure how to find undefined resources though.