# Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution (.resx)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I find and clean all the unused resources from a .resx file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by temporarily editing the Resources.Designer.cs file:

1. Turn on Code Analysis warning CA1811
2. In your Resources.Designer.CS file comment out the following lines:

   ```
   [global:: System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute( ...
   [global:: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
   ```
3. Change the class to a static class by putting the word "static" in front of "class":

   ```
   internal static class Resources {
   ```
4. Comment out the default constructor.
5. Compile your program. Now you should be warned about any unused resources.
6. Remove your unused resources (changing any resources will regenerate the `Resources.Designer.cs` file.)

That's it!

Comment: Good point, but isn't applicable to me. I translate my resources to js dictionary and use it in JS code.