# Find Unused Resources in a VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So first off I am prefacing this with I know this question has been asked before, it is here [Find Unused Resources in a .NET Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245956/find-unused-resources-in-a-net-solution) and I feel like it is so old that it is of little value to my current situation.

First here are the specs and requirements for this solution that would fit my needs.

- This has to work in/with VS 2012 Premium with  Web Essentials 2012 version 2.7
- I am committing to a TFS where 4 solutions are calling from a parent solution of common files, so media is split between the main parent solution and some from the children solution.  I don't have a ton of choices how this was setup so I have to live with it for the time being but I need to remove unused assets from all 5 solutions I am willing to take something that only lets me go one solution at a time and will just have to do some cross compare.
- I have tried normal string text searching into files looking for a specific image etc but there were a number of contractors working on this so some used a standard image reference and some used just css to put in an image via a background.  If this could check image issues in css files as well as html files or templates that would be great.

Comment: Anyone willing to help out with this?